# Unrecognized command line option -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm using Dev-C++.  When I'm trying to compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` I'm getting an error:

> Unrecognised command line option

Why?  And how can I solve it?

Comment: Your compiler is too old.

Answer (score 2):

Dev-C++ is a completely outdated IDE. It wasn't developed since 2005.

The reason why you get this error message though is the compiler - that's probably a GCC version back from that age as well, which of course didn't know anything about C++11 (or C++0x) at all.

Try to switch to [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) or the newest remake of Dev-C++, [Orwell Dev-C++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.co.uk/).